# C++ / destructor - operator delete

Tags: c++, memory, destructor, allocation, delete-operator

I was wondering if I have to delete this pointer in example like this :

```
class Person
{
  public:
    Person(char *name) :_name(name) {}

    // Is this delete necessary?
    ~Person() {
        cout<<"Godbay Person"<<endl;
        delete _name;
    }

  private:
    char * _name;
}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell, but most likely not. `Person` cannot even know if the pointer points to a dynamically allocated `char` or `char` array.

Comment: "Person cannot even know ..." name is field of Person class so should know that its pointer to dynamicly allocated char .

Comment: @AllanBradley In your code, `name` is a copy of a pointer passed to the constructor, so the class cannot possibly know whether it is dynamically allocated or not.  (Of course, in modern C++, I can't conceive of a case where you would dynamically allocate a `char` or an array of `char`.)

Comment: You cannot know from a pointer whether it has to be deleted at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty surely wrong in any case.

There are two possibilities:

1. The name is created on the free store exclusively for your object, and your object has to assume ownership. Then the name has to be deleted.
2. The name is not created on the free store (e.g. as a string litaral, which is quite possible), or some other object is managing the name, so your object should not assume ownership. Then any deletion would wreak havoc with your program.

So why do I say its wrong even in the first case? Because `name` sounds like a string, not a single character, wich means `name*` will point to an dynamically alocated array of characters. In that case, the correct way to delete it would be `delete[] name`.

**But:** If possible, **avoid using plain (char) pointers**, for case 1. Use some memory management class instead (a string class or smartpointers), to get rid of the headaches of manually managing memory ownership. `delete` and `delete[]` should appear only seldom in your code except if you don't have access to up-to-date C++ compilers.

Comment: There are cases where plain `char` pointers are valid; cases where the pointed to string must be a string literal, for example.  And there are cases where you don't have a choice; when you're interfacing to an interface defined in C.

Comment: @JamesKanze right, there are exceptions, I edited my answer accordingly. However, in both cases you mention a `delete[]` would be wrong, the string should either not be destroyed at all or it should be gven back to the interface where it came from. Which could/should be wrapped into a proper RAII class itself, e.g. a `shared/unique_ptr` with custom deleter.

Comment: In any well written code, `delete[]` would be wrong, because there's no case you should ever do a `new[]`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of who owns the allocated memory, in this case it *looks like* Person is not owning it so then no, so there is no need to delete. Using raw pointers like you do in `Person` always give rise to questions about ownership, that is why it is recommended to use `shared_ptr/unique_ptr` instead or even better `std::string` since it seems to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have to call delete each time you create a pointer with new.

Comment: This applies to pre-C++11 only. In C++11, you *should* use smart pointers, so *almost* any `new` you write is to give an object to a `unique_ptr`, and *almost* no deletes should be written. (Exceptions are own memory management classes). In C++14 `make_unique` makes those last `new`s obsolete as well.

Comment: Infact, tag is C++ not C++11.. (:

Comment: It is, but since C++11 has been standard for over two years now, *general* advices should be up to date.

Comment: @ArneMertz That's simply wrong.  The smart pointers (which have been around since long before C++11, just under different names) solve a few very specific problems, but they aren't a panacea, and can't be used universally.

Comment: @ArneMertz And the fact that C++11 has been the standard for over two years doesn't mean that it is universal, or even wide spread.

Comment: @JamesKanze I did not say either. All I wanted to point out is that with the presence of C++11 (and previous smartpointers as well), the general, unconditional guideline "every new needs a delete" does not apply any more.

Comment: @ArneMertz It applies in the same way it's always applied.  C++11 changed absolutely nothing there.

Comment: @JamesKanze well ok, let me rephrase that. "everything that has been new'd must (somehow) be deleted" still applies. The "*you* have to *call* delete..." we're talking about here does not. You don't have to explicitly *call* delete. You should not need to. You only have to *make sure* someone/something calls delete. Preferably not you, preferably some RAII class.

Comment: @ArneMertz First, there's no rule that _everything_ you allocate with new must be deleted; singletons often aren't.  Second, the rules concerning `new` and `delete` have not changed at all between C++11 and previous versions, nor have have the usual techniques for respecting them.  (And of course, one of the most frequent ways of deleting an object is with `delete this;`.  If you can use some RAII class, most of the time, you'd be better off not allocating dynamically to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on creation procedure.

In this case no:

```
Person *p = new Person("John");
```

In this case yes:

```
char *str = new char[32];
::strcpy(str, "John");
Person *p = new Person(str);
```

In this case yes, but with `::free` function rather than operator `delete`.

```
char *str = (char *)::malloc(32);
::strcpy(str, "John");
Person *p = new Person(str);
```

Consider using `std::string` instead of C string pointer.